# Is it possible to describe derived params in xml summary document?

Tags: visual-studio, xml-documentation

For example, if I have an interface with an operation like `public ResponseBase DoWork(RequestBase);`.  I want to create a summary that describes all of the derived requests and responses that can be used.  I cant change the interface to use overloads because 1) it is an anti-pattern and doesn't follow SOLID principles and 2) the request can produce any one of multiple response objects.